# How to transcode to hevc losslessly using ffmpeg hevc_qsv encoder?

Tags: ffmpeg, codec, hardware-acceleration

I'm using `ffmpeg -hwaccel qsv -c:v h264_qsv -i Intro.mkv -strict -2 -c:v hevc_qsv -preset veryslow -c:a copy Intro-hevc.mp4` to transcode a h264 mkv video to hevc mp4.  Although the file size is reduced.  The image quality is very bad.  So, How can I tanscode to hevc losslessly using hevc_qsv encoder?

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the resolution and video bitrates.

I don't know about hevc but h264 qsv has a profile option. Try applying that not to mention you have to put hevcqsv (or h265 qsv I have no idea check ffmpeg documentation and media SDK docs) option in place of h264qsv in the -c:v flag or else it will be encoding in h264.

Answer (score 0):

With hevc_qsv it is not possible to transcode lossless.

But you can define `-global_quality` with values from 1 (almost lossless) to 51 (not suitable to watch) to control the quality. This enables ICQ mode, which behave similar to the `-crf` factor, where crf 23 roughly equals the same quality as a global_quality of 25.

Another option is to use `libx265`, but then you would not benefit of the hardware acceleration. In real world there is no visible difference in quality between any factor smaller than 15 to the lossless version. Even 20 is really good. It only increases the filesize.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know how to do it with FFMPEG but you can use HandBrake.

[encoders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDZyG.png)
As you can see in the screenshot, there are all encoders listed I can use. Just select the H.265 (Intel QSV) and select quality as 0.